# Solar system design: Inverter keep tripping problem

Tags: inverter, battery-operated, solar-energy

What is the problem when my 2kW pressure washer can only use for 3 to 5 minutes? The inverter drop to 50v and then tripped. My solar system consist of 48v 200Ah battery bank with 3000w inverter (48v system, peak 6000w) and 4 pv panels (290w 32.6v 8.9A per panel, series-parallel connection) charge by 60A mppt controller.

Comment: Measure the battery voltage, if it didn't drop, then the inverter is bad, low quality.

Comment: What kind of wire do you have from battery to inverter? What is the diameter of the wire (or AWG if you are in North America) and how long is the wire? One common problem with inverters is that people use wires that are too small in diameter or too long between battery and inverter.

Answer (score 1):

A pressure washer has a high crest factor for current meaning the current is not sinusoidal and pk/RMS is not 1.414 but could be > 3:1 sustained and not just on startup.  i.e. > 6kW peak power sustained but 2kW average.

(If so) This, in turn, causes I^2 *R  losses that exceed the peak power capacity and result in excessive self-heating slowly then inductor saturation which in turn causes thermal runaway and shutdown.